# How do you get cattrs to unstructure nested structures?

Tags: python, python-attrs, python-cattrs

In Python, with the libraries `attrs` and `cattrs`, I have a nested structure defined as follows:

```py
@attrs.define
class Score:
    added: datetime
    value: float


@attrs.define
class Entry:
    score: Score
    tags: List[str]
    added: Optional[datetime] = None


@attrs.define
class Entries:
    entries: Dict[date, Entry] = attrs.Factory(dict)
```

With this data:

```py
data = {
    'entries': {
        '2024-01-01': {
            'score': {'added': '2023-02-03 04:03:00', 'value': 80.3},
            'tags': ['meatball', 'salami', 'jerky'],
        },
        # … more days
    }
}
```

And some `un/structure` hooks to handle the `date` and `datetime` types:

```py
cattrs.register_unstructure_hook(datetime, lambda dt: datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
cattrs.register_structure_hook(datetime, lambda dt, _: str(dt))
cattrs.register_unstructure_hook(date, lambda dt: datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
cattrs.register_structure_hook(date, lambda dt, _: str(dt))
```

Now when I destructure an instance of `Entries`, the resulting `dict` does not have the `date` and `datetime` objects in string form:

```py
structured = cattrs.structure(data, Entries)

cattrs.unstructure(structured) == {
    'entries': {
        datetime.date(2024, 1, 1): {
            'score': {
                'added': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 3, 4, 3),
                'value': 80.3
            },
            'tags': ['meatball', 'salami', 'jerky'],
            'added': None
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get cattrs to stringify `date` and `datetime` objects recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hooks don't seem correct. Your *unstructure* hooks should make the types simpler (so, from datetimes to strings), and your *structure* hooks should add structure to the data (so, from strings to datetimes).

So, for the unstructure hooks:

```py
# Takes a datetime, returns a string
cattrs.register_unstructure_hook(datetime, lambda dt: dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

# Takes a date, returns a string
cattrs.register_unstructure_hook(date, lambda dt: dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

and for the structure hooks:

```py
# Takes a string, returns a datetime
cattrs.register_structure_hook(
    datetime, lambda dt, _: datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
)

# Takes a string, returns a date
cattrs.register_structure_hook(
    date, lambda dt, _: datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
)
```

After applying these modifications your example seems to work. Good luck!